# Adding globally defined objects for Intellisense and linting to Monaco Editor in javascript/typescript

Tags: intellisense, monaco-editor

I have a working Monaco editor in a React app that correctly underlines out javascript errors.

I am trying to register an object called `data` that I have defined as a JSON schema, so that:

1. Typing the letter 'd' in the code editor would prompt intellisense to suggest `data`
2. Intellisense would correctly suggest all the properties of the `data` object, and the properties of all of its child properties according to the JSON schema
3. The editor does not show an undefined variable error when data is used.

I have tried to use monarch to register data as a keyword but am only managing to handle the coloring and error handling, not the properties suggestion.

I also looked at [registerDocumentSymbolProvider](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#registerDocumentSymbolProvider). [registerCompletionItemProvider](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#registerCompletionItemProvider) and [registerDeclarationProvider](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#registerCompletionItemProvider) (I think the last one will help with intellisense but not with getting rid of the undefined error) but I don't understand what the purpose of each are and the documentation only defines their usage with sentences like "registers a document symbol provider" which I haven't so far found very helpful.

Would appreciate any help with this. I am excited to use the more advanced features of this great tool but the steep learning curve and my inability to find information has left me pretty disheartened so far!